# How can I change the progress bar in scrollable quiz/form to appear like a timeline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a quiz (four questions) and a sign up form after completion of quiz.

I got started using a [scrollable registration wizard](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/wizard.html) script and created the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/HVX4C/

```
    <!-- twitter style "drawer" for displaying validation errors -->
    <div id="drawer">[ERROR MESSAGE]</div>

    <!-- the form -->
    <form action="#">

      <!-- scrollable root element -->
      <div id="wizard">

        <!-- status bar -->
        <ul id="status">
          <li class="active">1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
        </ul>

        <!-- scrollable items -->
        <div class="items">
          <!-- pages -->
          <div class="page">[ Any HTML content ]</div><!-- 1 -->
          <div class="page">[ Any HTML content ]</div><!-- 2 -->
          <div class="page">[ Any HTML content ]</div><!-- 3 -->
          <div class="page">[ Any HTML content ]</div><!-- 4 -->
          <div class="page">[ Any HTML content ]</div><!-- 5 -->
          <div class="page">[ Any HTML content ]</div><!-- 6 -->
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

As you can see, there are four questions, and once you get to step 5 you see a sign up form.

I'm trying to customize it in such a way so that the progress bar contains a timeline instead of just numbers, and have it indicate the current state of the user:
[image]

Also, I want to have an indicator that expresses whether the user get the question right or wrong:

[image]

[image]

Any thoughts on how can I achieve this? Would kindly appreciate any advice/suggestions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a matter off CSS styling to change the way it looks then some jquery to add/remove classes depending on successful answer or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer the first part of my question and changed the progress bar to appear as a timeline. See below:

```
  <div id="wizard">
    <ul id="status">
      <li class="active" style="margin-left: -5px;"><p>1948</p></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 25px;"><p>1950</p></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 25px;"><p>1960</p></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 25px;"><p>1980</p></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 25px;"><p>1990</p></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 25px;"><p>2000</p></li>
    </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/vG7Uw/1/

Now I'm trying to figure out how to add an indicator that expresses whether the user gets the question right or wrong. Will follow @Tip_Top's advice of getting some validation before the user can proceed.